# How to get the "upload image" field using Nicedit editor

Tags: javascript, html, nicedit

my code is

Html code:

```
<div id="sample">

<script type="text/javascript" src="../nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
</script>
<h4>First Textarea</h4>
<textarea name="area1" cols="35"></textarea>
</div>
```

The above code convert the text area into editor.
I need a one more option for that editor that should be able to upload images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options) you will need to specify a `uploadURI` for that und upload their [nicUpload.php](http://svn.nicedit.com//trunk/nicUpload/php/nicUpload.php) script to that location.

Inside the [nicUpload.php](http://svn.nicedit.com//trunk/nicUpload/php/nicUpload.php) you will need to configure some parameters. `NICUPLOAD_PATH`as a filesystem path on the server where the images should be stored and `NICUPLOAD_URI` to the URI to access said location through the webserver.

Don't forget to chmod write permissions onto the directory so the webserver can write there.